# Phpmyadmin : Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Yes, another question about the infamous error "**Cannot log in to the MySQL server**".

I read all the questions / answers on StackOverflow about this problem, but none of this solves my problems

**Apache** (v2.4.9) and **Php** (v5.5.14) works perfectly, now I need to also install **phpmyadmin** to manage the database, so I followed this simple [guide](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/installing-phpmyadmin-on-mac-osx-10-7-lion/)

But when I login to phpmyadmin I find myself in front of this error

[image]

This is my */Webserver/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php* configuration file

```
<?php
/*
 * Generated configuration file
 * Generated by: phpMyAdmin 4.3.8 setup script
 * Date: Mon, 26 Jan 2015 20:49:39 +0000
 */

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'it';
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '54c6a5b31f8851.41343068';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
?>
```

i tried to edit this

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

to this

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

or this

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

but the problem persists

---

### UPDATE

I solved my problem by using this command:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'newpassword'
```

Comment: are you sure your sql server runs?

Comment: Some installations of mysql have turned on `skip-networking` in the config by default. If that is the case you can only connect to your database using socket path.

Comment: Also if this is for you local development environment i would recommend not using phpmyadmin at all... Use [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) or [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

Comment: @Eugen , how can i check it ?

Comment: command line mysql, log in

Comment: post your system os?

Comment: @Eugen OS X Yosemite 10.10.1

Comment: @Dagon mysql on command line = command not found

Comment: You can then start the MySQL server from the System Preferences or via the command line.  look here http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/#mysql

Comment: I tried again the whole procedure on another mac, but I have the exact same problem. it's a problem of mysql? Having phpmyadmin installed in the following directory (/ Library / Webserver / Documents / phpmyadmin), where it should be installed MYSQL? Currently I know here (/ usr / local / mysql), although that address would point to (/usr/local/mysql-5.6.22-osx10.8-x86_64)

Comment: i solved my problem by using this command: `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'newpassword'`

Comment: @WhiteLine Did you edit  password in `config.inic.php` too? I'm having this annoying issue past ~6 hours..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would fix your problem - but, when I deleted the files in the folder C:\lamp\data - such as the log files etc, it let me log in again to the phpmyadmin